# HTML/CSS | Разворачивающийся-сворачивающийся список

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

**Есть вот такой блок:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**код html** (стили прикреплять не буду, слишком много кода):

```html
<div>
    <div>SERVER MANAGEMENT</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <a>Приветствия</a>
    <a>Модератор</a>
    <a>Реакции с ролями</a>
</ul>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `SERVER MANAGEMENT` `список ul` сворачивался, а при повторном нажатии разворачивался.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Реализовать можно так. Создаёте развёрнутый блок, задаёте ему display:none; Далее черёд js обрабатывает клик по нужному элементу и добавляете класс ddisplay:Block.

Comment: А как поймать клик по `div` блоку?

Comment: Лично я в таких случаях использую jquery.

Comment: CSS-way: `.outer-div:focus ~ ul { <стили_чтобы_сворачивался> }`, при наличии `tabindex` у внешнего div-элемента. JS-way: `anyDivElem.addEventListener('click', () => ulElem.classList.toggle('chtoby-svorachivalsya'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.menu-header').on(`click`, function() {
  $(this).next().stop(true).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}

ul a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-header">
  <div>SERVER MANAGEMENT</div>
</div>
<ul>
  <a>Приветствия</a>
  <a>Модератор</a>
  <a>Реакции с ролями</a>
</ul>
```